# How should I create the relational schema to be able to "join" in the oracle database? Which columns do I need to associate with which key?

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a table but forgot to select primary and foreign key to join the table.
How can I fix this process?

Comment: Technically, those don't need to be declared to join two tables.  The primary key does create an index, so declaring one makes things faster.

Comment: Just to expand on what Gordon Linoff stated, there is no inherent connection between primary/foreign keys and JOINing tables.  It's quite normal to have properly normalized tables with well defined PKs and FKs, and still have a requirement for a particular query to JOIN on other columns.  That said, as part of your data analysis and normalization, you should be identifying proper PKs and possible FKs.  But data normalization and design should be driven by data relationships, not the needs of a particular query or report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ALTER TABLE Statement

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT MyPrimaryKey 
PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2...);

ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT MyForeignKey 
FOREIGN KEY (column1) REFERENCES Table(column);
```